# how to improve quality of skype call

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

how to improve the quality of skype call using skype4com c#. I am actually recording the skype voice call using skype4com. The problem i am facing is that i can hear my own voice good enough but the voice of the other person is not good when recorded. I hear too much noise even if i turn the microphone off when recording it.

```
        rVolume = lVolume = aVolume = tVolume = 1000;
        bVolume = 0;
        Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio {0} volume to {1}", Phandle, aVolume);
        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0) ;

         Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio {0} right volume to {1}", Phandle, rVolume);
        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0) ;

         Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio {0} left volume to {1}", Phandle, lVolume);
         if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0) ;

         Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio {0} bass to {1}", Phandle, bVolume);
         if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0);
```

this is the code that i am using to improve the quality of skype call is that going to work ? or will this just effect the windows volume only? add any thing that u think should be added here to improve the quality and make the sound more clear.

Comment: Only you can tell us if it works.

Comment: Changing the volume does not improve the quality of the call - for that you need to adjust the samplerate of voice that's being transmitted compared to how stable and fast your data connection is at that instant. You might want to look up *QoS Engines*.